# Best practise to model custom *relations* with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Whats the best practise in Spring Boot to model *custom* relations between two entities in projection.

My entity `Participation` links to `Competition`, `User` and `Team`.

```
public class Participation
{
    @Id
    private String id;

    @NonNull
    @OneToOne
    private Competition competition;

    @OneToOne
    private Team team;

    @NonNull
    @OneToOne
    private User user;

    private String info;
}
```

In my project, I want to link all participating `Users` for a specific `Team` to a `Competition`. To achieve this, I wrote a `CompetitionDTO` that has a field `List<User> participants` that is filled by a custom `CompetitionService`:

```
public Page<CompetitionDTO> teamParticipations (Team team, Pageable pageable)
{
    Page<CompetitionDTO> page = cRep.findTeamParticipation(team, pageable);
    page.forEach(competition -> competition.setParticipants(pRep.findParticipants(competition, team)));
    return page;
}
```

I don't like this approach a lot because I assume there is a more elegant way to do this with Spring.

Comment: 1. Why are all associations one-to-one (as opposed to many-to-one)? 2. Isn't `Participation.team` redundant in the current design? Can a single user switch teams/belong to more than one team? 3. Judiging by the use case you describe, wouldn't it make more sense to have a list of users in `Participation`, or a list of intermediate entities composed of `User` and `info` (i.e. a `TeamParticipation` entity containing a list of `UserParticipation`)?

Comment: Thanks for your response @crizzis. 1. You're right, many-to-one is correct here. 
2. Yes a user can have multiple teams and switch between them. I decided for this design, because it is easier to switch teams. (I don't have to look for/avoid duplicates) 3. A competition is the main entity in  this project. So every additional information should be attached to or related from this object.

Comment: I can't see how competition being the main entity invalidates the design `Competition has-many TeamParticipation has-many UserParticipation`. You'd still be able to query for all users and all teams from a particular `Competition`, for instance